# Assigning scope value from array is throwing error

Tags: angularjs

```js
module.exports = function ($http, $log, $scope, $modalInstance, myService, name, value, searchType, advancedSearchValue, $location,$q) {
  $scope.download = function(value, searchType, advancedSearchValue) {
   return myService.getFileDownload($scope.value, $scope.searchType,$scope.advancedSearchValue[0].firstname,$scope.advancedSearchValue[0].lastname).then(function (result) {
     //Processing for file download
});
}
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I have an array with 2 values

```
advancedSearchValue= [{"firstname":"Name","lastname":"SurName"}]
$scope.datas=advancedSearchValue;
```

If I try to assign the value to from array I am not able to assign the value,

```
$scope.firstname = $scope.datas[0].firstname;
```

But If I try to display the record it is displaying in console.log. Please let me know how to get the value and assign it.
I have a tricky condition to get the value where there is a normal search using name and advanced search using fName and lName and I am making a service call within the download method,

```
$scope.download = function(value, searchType, advancedSearchValue) {
   return myService.getFileDownload($scope.value, $scope.searchType,$scope.advancedSearchValue[0].firstname,$scope.advancedSearchValue[0].lastname).then(function (result) {
     //Processing for file download
});
}
```

if the name with value comes it is normal search but incase of advancedSearchValue[0].firstname the values won't get populated and I need to set the value according to searchType. But If pass the value directly for advanced search it is working with the parameters $scope.advancedSearchValue[0].firstname. But if I try to pass normal name search the value wont be there in advancedSearchValue[0] and it is throwing cannot read property for "0". But if I try to get the value also I am not able to get the value from $scope.advancedSearchValue[0].firstname. Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you create fiddle for it, as in we're not able catch what  exactly do you want.

Comment: Please provide a jsfidle or a code snippet

Comment: It is a big application and I am using small modification. I have the code as mentioned in code snippet where there are 2 conditions one will have $scope.value and other will have $scope.advancedSearchValue[0].firstname,$scope.advancedSearchValue[0].lastname and calling route service. The problem is If I pass $scope.value $scope.advancedSearchValue[0].firstname is expecting and getting cannot read the property for '0'. Please suggest how to handle this condition

Comment: What are you passing in $scope.value?

Comment: $scope.value is for normal search condition and I am getting the value as some sample name and the other condition is field search I have first name and last name as ($scope.value $scope.advancedSearchValue[0].firstname , $scope.value $scope.advancedSearchValue[0].lastname). I have a parameter to segregate the search type but if I try to search normally it is expecting a value for $scope.advancedSearchValue. Please let me know if you need any other info

Comment: Do one thing for normal search send only needed parameter,rest of the will be undefined by default and for your advanced search send needful params.

Comment: I have created a object with null and if condition for advanced using searchType to add data.Thanks Pravin